# Point charge between parallel plates

Tags: ground, electrostatic

Let's say we have 2 grounded parallel plates and we place a charge Q between them.

I'm studying Green's reciprocity theorem and in using it the author states that the  **charge induced on the plates is such that** $$-Q=q_1+q_2$$
where q1 and q2 are the total charge on each plate. It is stated that this happens because the plates are grounded.

That isn't enough for me, I'm forgetting something important or I haven't understood how the distribution works. I'm thinking if it was one plate the charge on it would be -Q so, since we have two plates, each plate should have charge -Q. So **why does the total charge induced have to cancel the point charge Q**?

Comment: If the plates are grounded, any charge you contribute is free to move anywhere else.

Comment: If we place a charge Q next to a single grounded plate the charge induced on the plate will be opposite of the charge  Q so Q=-Q1induced. Now we place a second grounded plate which because of the charge Q will also get charge -Q so again Q=-Q2induced. This is not true though. What actually happens is -Q=Q1+Q2.  Why ?

Comment: Because if  on both surfaces induce charge is -Q ,so total charge would be -2Q but it is impossible that electric field  lines emerging from Q should end on -2Q, because theoretically equal charge causes equal electric field lines .

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer , but would be helpful to other users .

> why total induce charges have to cancel charge Q?

Rather than Mathematical answer using method of images and Green's theorem , I'll try to give an intuitive answer of this question .

In 1st Case - **A grounded infinite conducting plate and a point charge Q**

We know , Charges are induce in conductors due to induction effect but how much charge will induce on the surface towards point charge Q will depend on-

1.proportional to Size of conductor 2.inversely proportional to distance between  charge and conductor

And how much maximum charge can be induced and in which conditions ?

And the answer is obvious **if all the electric field emerging from Q ends on induce Charges on plate and for that induce charges on conductor surface (towards Q) must be be -Q**

And condition for this to happen is - if

**(Size of Conductor /Distance between the conductor and Q) tends to infinity** and potential of infinite plate is Zero

Since ,we assume that grounded conducting plate is of infinite size so condition for induce charge equal to -Q satisfy. And electrostatic energy will be stored between conductor and Q only .

In 2nd Case- Two grounded infinite conducting plate and a point charge Q .

Again , since we assume that plates are of infinite size and are grounded  , so maximum charge will be induced but how much ?

**This time again all the electric field emerging from Q ends on the both plates, so the sum of induce charges of surfaces(towards Q) should be equal to -Q.** i.e
$$Q_1+Q_2=-Q$$ .

And important thing to note that -value of  $$ Q_1 and Q_2 $$  depends on position of Q alone because no electric field emerge from surface of plate 1 and ends on plate 2 because they are equipotential .